# Get x random rows from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have read this question:
[What is the best way to get a random ordering?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering)
and can do a `select top 4 from tabel order by NEWID()` **but** I need it per category.
So I need 1 row from category A, 1 row from category B, 1 row from category C **and** 1 row from *parent*category D.

So I tried to union them and I tried to add a wrapping select query which told me that I could not order the subquery... So I am stuck.

Here is the SQL I have so far:

```
SELECT top 4 Artikel.ArtikelID -- etc.
FROM Artikel 
INNER JOIN Categorie ON Artikel.CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID 
INNER JOIN CategorieTaal ON Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID 
INNER JOIN CategorieGroep on Categorie.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID
INNER JOIN CategorieGroepTaal on CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroepTaal.CategorieGroepID
INNER JOIN Taal ON CategorieTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode AND ArtikelTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode and CategorieGroepTaal.TaalCode = taal.TaalCode
INNER JOIN Levertijd ON Artikel.LevertijdID = Levertijd.LevertijdID 
WHERE (ParentCategorieID = 292 or artikel.CategorieID = 246 or artikel.CategorieID = 247 or artikel.CategorieID = 288)
and taal.taalcode = 'EN'
order by NEWID()
```

current result could contain 4 rows all of the same category. That is not what I want. It's a bit different than the possible duplicate because it is not grouped on 1 column, but two different once.

Comment: Related: [Retrieving n rows per group](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group)

Comment: I have used the `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION ` before but I do not know what the best approach is, since the fourth row should be from a certain parentcategory instead of normal category. I have never looked into `Apply` so will do that asap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's simplify the problem because I think it will be easier to visualize when you don't start adding in the complication of joins and other clauses.

Let's think about objects in the system catalog `sys.all_objects`, and say you want one of each of the following object types in the resultset:

- table (`'U'`)
- procedure (`'P'`)
- view (`'V'`)
- any type of function (`'FN'`, `'IF'`, `'FS'`, `'AF'`, `'TF'`)

The whole set is simply:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects 
WHERE type IN (N'U',N'P',N'V',N'FN',N'IF',N'FS',N'AF',N'TF');
```

To get a single, random row from each type (or set of types), you can say:

```
;WITH wholeset AS 
(
  SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (
      PARTITION BY CASE 
        WHEN [type] IN (N'FN',N'IF',N'FS',N'AF',N'TF') 
          THEN N'FN'
        ELSE
          [type]
        END ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
  FROM sys.all_objects 
  WHERE type IN (N'U',N'P',N'V',N'FN',N'IF',N'FS',N'AF',N'TF')
)
SELECT * FROM wholeset WHERE rn = 1;
```

Applying similar logic to your query, assuming `-1` is not a valid category, in which case you could use `-999` or some other impossible token value:

```
;WITH wholeset AS
(
  SELECT ...cols..., rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER
    (
      PARTITION BY CASE 
        WHEN Categorie.ParentCategorie = 292 THEN -1 
        ELSE Artikel.Categorie 
      END ORDER BY NEWID()
    )
  FROM dbo.Artikel -- always use dbo prefix
  INNER JOIN dbo.Categorie ON Artikel.CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID 
  INNER JOIN dbo.CategorieTaal ON Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID 
  INNER JOIN dbo.CategorieGroep on Categorie.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID
  INNER JOIN dbo.CategorieGroepTaal on CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroepTaal.CategorieGroepID
  INNER JOIN dbo.Taal ON CategorieTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode AND ArtikelTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode and CategorieGroepTaal.TaalCode = taal.TaalCode
  INNER JOIN dbo.Levertijd ON Artikel.LevertijdID = Levertijd.LevertijdID 
  WHERE (Categorie.ParentCategorieID = 292 or artikel.CategorieID = 246 or artikel.CategorieID = 247 or artikel.CategorieID = 288)
  AND taal.taalcode = 'EN'
)
SELECT * FROM wholeset WHERE rn = 1;
```

There are some edge cases here, like if you don't have any rows in a category, or if you only have one row that is in the parent category *and* that is the only row in one of the other three categories as well. But for most data sets this should work pretty reliably.

Answer (score 0):

A solution (it's perhaps not THE solution, but it gives me the expected results)

```
SELECT top 1 WITH TIES Artikel.ArtikelID -- etc.
FROM Artikel 
INNER JOIN Categorie ON Artikel.CategorieID = Categorie.CategorieID 
INNER JOIN CategorieTaal ON Categorie.CategorieID = CategorieTaal.CategorieID 
INNER JOIN CategorieGroep on Categorie.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID
INNER JOIN CategorieGroepTaal on CategorieGroep.CategorieGroepID = CategorieGroepTaal.CategorieGroepID
INNER JOIN Taal ON CategorieTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode AND ArtikelTaal.TaalCode = Taal.TaalCode and CategorieGroepTaal.TaalCode = taal.TaalCode
INNER JOIN Levertijd ON Artikel.LevertijdID = Levertijd.LevertijdID 
WHERE (ParentCategorieID = 292 or artikel.CategorieID = 246 or artikel.CategorieID = 247 or artikel.CategorieID = 288)
and taal.taalcode = 'EN'
Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By case when artikel.CategorieID in  (251,252,255,265,269,273,285,289,290,327) then 'C'
                    else 
                        case when artikel.CategorieID = 246 then 'q' else 
                            case when artikel.CategorieID = 247 then 'P' else 
                                case when artikel.CategorieID = 288 then 'L' else null end 
                        end
                    end
                end Order By NewID())
```