# Generate random row order in a subquery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, random

I know other answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117761/return-rows-in-random-order) (and [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/955/what-is-the-best-way-to-get-a-random-ordering)) say to order by `newid()`. However if I am selecting `top 1` in a subquery - so as to generate a random selection per row in the outer query - using `newid()` yields the same result each time.

That is:

```
select *,
    (select top 1 [value] from lookupTable where [code] = 'TEST' order by newid())
from myTable
```

... yields the same `lookupTable.value` value on each row returned from `myTable`.

I'm trying to pick a random value from `lookupTable`. That table has only a few rows. In the real world I want to `update myTable set someColumn =`  ... a random `lookupTable.value` value such that each row in `myTable` is set with a random value and not such that a single random value is generated and assigned to all rows.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to achieve this is to ensure the subquery is correlated i.e. it depends in some way on the outer query. Using an AdventureWorks example:

```
SELECT 
    E.BusinessEntityID,
    R.DepartmentID
FROM HumanResources.Employee AS E
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP (1)
        D.DepartmentID
    FROM HumanResources.Department AS D
    ORDER BY 
        NEWID(),
        CHECKSUM(E.BusinessEntityID, D.DepartmentID) -- Correlation
) AS R;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&sample=adventureworks&fiddle=7c48d14d037a91e7f972550830fbec63)

Without the correlation, SQL Server recognises that the inner query logically only needs to be run once.

The example above uses `CHECKSUM(E.BusinessEntityID, D.DepartmentID)` to ensure the intended correlation remains after query optimization. If we just add `E.BusinessEntityID`, the optimizer realizes its value is constant per iteration, removes the dependency, and we're back where we started.

The semantics of the example are also slightly different from the query in the question. It does not return NULL if *lookupTable* is empty.

Comment: Ok, so framing it to match the original question, the cross apply can be avoided, and the result can be achieved using `order by newid(), checksum(myTable.anyColumn, lookupTable.anyColumn)`. Shame MS doesn't simply allow a keyword phrase like `with(not deterministic)`.